# How to use output buffer in php for middle content

Tags: php, output, buffer

I am making a website with large query which will take 5 to 7 second to execute,all queries will run like this.My page structure is like this:

```
header.php
Query1
Query2
Query3
Query4
Query5
footer.php
```

I wants to show data to user when Query1 is executed ,i am using `ob_start()` and `ob_flush()` for this,its working fine But my footer get disappeared until all queries completed.I wants to show my header and footer instantly and flush the data in middle section.
**I have made a Modle for it,Model code is.**

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>

<div class="container" style="height:400px;">
    <div class="row">

            <?PHP
            ob_start();
            $buffer = str_repeat(" ", 4096)."\r\n<span></span>\r\n";

            for ($i=0; $i<25; $i++) {
            echo $buffer.$i;
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            sleep(1);
            }
            echo $uu;
            ob_end_flush();
            ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php include('footer.php') ;
```

In this example footer will come after whole query is executed,how to flush data only a selected reason.Please help. Thanxx in Advance

Comment: You can't do it this way.

Comment: Any Suggestion Please ?

Comment: use an AJAX call